# Making std::optional a monad via SFINAE

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

To practice with SFINAE, template meta programming, functional programming and monads in C++, I decided to try writing a skinny version of the two functions (monadic binding and return) that make `std::optional` a monad.

Here's the result:

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename TD = std::decay_t<T>, typename = void>
struct is_optional : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename TD>
struct is_optional<
    T,
    TD,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<TD,std::optional<typename TD::value_type>>>
    > : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_optional_v = is_optional<T>::value;

template<typename T, typename F, typename = void>
struct MBind {
    inline constexpr auto operator()(T&&, F&&) const noexcept = delete;
};

template<typename T, typename F>
struct MBind<T, F, std::enable_if_t<
    is_optional_v<T> && is_optional_v<decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T>().value()))>
    >> {
    template<typename Opt = T, typename Fun = F>
    inline constexpr auto operator()(Opt&& opt, Fun&& f) const noexcept {
        return opt ? f(*std::forward<T>(opt)) : decltype(f(*std::forward<T>(opt))){};
    }
};

inline constexpr auto mbind = [](auto&& t, auto&& f) noexcept {
    return MBind<decltype(t), decltype(f)>{}(
            std::forward<decltype(t)>(t),std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)
            );
};

inline constexpr auto mreturn = [](auto&& x){
    return std::make_optional(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x));
};

int main()
{
    auto xxx1 = mbind(std::optional<int>{1}, [](auto){ return mreturn(3.3); }); // Ok
    //auto xxx2 = mbind(std::optional<int>{1}, [](auto){ return 1; });          // wrong F
    //auto xxx3 = mbind(std::vector<int>{1,2}, [](auto){ return mreturn(3); }); // wrong T
}
```

A few points on which I'd like to receive some feedback, beside any other comments that the code above needs.

- I know I've written a meta-function `is_optional_v` which doesn't really enforce that `T` satisfies the general concept of a *maybe*, but requires that it is exactly a `std::optional`; my target was not to learn writing concepts (yet).
- For invalid types I've `deleted` the `operator()` that actually does the binding, so I have no place to put any message like `` "this is not a `std::optional`, man" ``; the same hold also for the metafunction `is_optional_v`; actually, probably the latter, not `MBind::operator()`, should be responsible for issueing a compiler message about the input being not a `std::optional`, whereas `MBind::operator()` should probably be responsible for complaining about the monadic function passed in. (Probably I think this is really a matter of personal preference, as I think this is what Louis Dionne says [here](https://youtu.be/emHnx_ZG0qc?t=1868).)
- I have tried to perfect forwarding things whenever it makes sense, but I'm not really sure I've done it the right way.
- I have templated `MBind` and not (just) its `operator()` to allow me partial specialization so that I could use the SFINAE-`std::enable_if` idiom.
- I have defaulted the template parameters of `operator()` to those of the class, because (as explained above) I didn't want to make everything that behaves like an optional a monad; I think I would do that via [tag dispatching](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-core-tag_dispatching) when I get more comfortable with this stuff.
- Have I exagerated with `inline` and `constexpr`? Or, is any of those superfluous or inherently a *bad* idea?

Comment: [`constexpr` implies `inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391272/does-constexpr-imply-inline)